# What are these PHP tags called?

Tags: php

Instead of `<?php print $somevar; ?>` you can write `<?= $somevar; ?>`.

The reason I ask is that my php configuration does not seem to be evaluating these and I need to know the name so I can change php.ini.

Comment: PHP >= 5.3. will set this setting by default to false. So in future releases of PHP you always have to change this setting and if you are not the administrator, you will have some trouble. So, I suggest you change this in your source code to be future-proof.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am the administrator though so it isn't a big problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are called [short-tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Oh, and keep in mind, short tags have been said to be deprecated in 6 and will be removed later (I haven't been able to find a working link, sorry)...  There's some [distention](http://cubicspot.blogspot.com/2009/06/maximum-failure-php-6-deprecates-short.html) among the community about this, so time will tell...

Comment: " tags have been said to be deprecated in 6" do you have any official reference for that? Unfortunately i couldn't find anything official about that, honestly, i love using `<?= ?>`in templates, clearly separating pure output from logic.

Comment: I found a few links, but nothing from an official source...  Here are a few: [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413661/php6-is-short-open-tag-removed-or-deprecated-or-neither), [CodeIgniter Thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/94801/#479661), [NYPHP Thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/talk@lists.nyphp.org/msg09084.html)...

Comment: @Hannes/@ircmaxell: see below, I pasted the ini-comment. I guess they finally want to become rid of options they recommend everyone to avoid anyway.

Comment: hmmm... f*ck (excuse my language) i completely see the point with `<? ?>`... but `<?= ?>` are really an addition ... But @initall the ini comment isn't in any way a statement that it gets deprecated in 6, it only advices not to use it under some special circumstances, not even in general

Comment: @Hannes: No need to play the f*ck-card. If they want to get rid of it, the next major release would be a good moment. Like safe_mode. I just support the assumption it could happen in 6 and don't blame your favor for short tags in any way.

Comment: @Hannes:  Personally, I fully support removing `<?`.  It makes it a PITA to embed valid XML/XHTML in PHP, since it'll pick up on `<?xml` as a php start tag and give you a fatal error.  `<? ` and `<?= ` are both non-standard xml processing instruction extensions (You need to have a `Name` element after the `<?`: [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) ).  So while I understand the distain about removing the potentially useful `<?=`, it will help PHP become standard XML.  So perhaps another syntax should be developed...

Answer (score 2):

Short open tags

Answer (score 1):

As others said, they're called `short_open_tags` . Relying on these is considered "bad" because it depends on a INI setting and affects your code's portability.

Comment: "because it depends on a INI setting and affects your code's portability" as does nearly every other php.ini setting

Comment: Yes, but other INI settings does not necessarily crash your script and most can be worked around. Not this one: if it can't be enabled and you're using it, you're screwed.

Comment: You can override that setting generally using `php_flag` from within `.htaccess`, or your custom suexec/fastcgi php.ini on professional hosters. (It's seriously uncommon to be disabled anyways.)

Comment: so you say there is no Option in the php.ini that, if set to one value or the other has ANY chance of crashing a page? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Open or short tags

Answer (score 1):

```
; Allow the <? tag.  Otherwise, only <?php and <script> tags are recognized.
; NOTE: Using short tags should be avoided when developing applications or
; libraries that are meant for redistribution, or deployment on PHP
; servers which are not under your control, because short tags may not
; be supported on the target server. For portable, redistributable code,
; be sure not to use short tags.
short_open_tag = On
```

Answer (score 1):

short_open_tags = On or Off in php.ini